# Can we attach JMS Queue to Existing MDB at run time

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms

Can we attach JMS Queue to Existing MDB at run time?

Can any one give Example for this.

Thanks is advance.

Comment: This is server-specific.

Answer (score 0):

@user574557: actually it should be asked reverse way: how to attach existing MDB to another queue?
Ofcourse this is server specific. Generally if your server has JCA based MDBs then, it would require to re-initialize MDBs with different JMS activation spec. You can refer to JCA specification.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, But I didn't get your comment "You can refer to JCA specification.".